# I want to make installation of my Visual Studio 2017 project , how to achieve that?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I have database,images and text files in my project and i would like to make instalation..
Also I would like to put prerequirements so that people who install this must install version of .net framework i used in my project
What is the best way to achieve that?

UPDATE:

I wanted to use microsoft visual studio installer but it doesnt work .. it doenst create exe file and i cant open app

Comment: You can generate a MSI package from Visual Studio - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766795.aspx

Comment: Why not use a Visual Studio installer project? See this:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Comment: VS install project is no longer available in 2013 or 2015+. Looks like they have ditched support for that. I wouldn't use it for new projects

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used [NSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) for making installers.  It has an extensible scripting bit to put whatever prerequisites you need(TOS, EULA, ect.) and it can easily create a professional looking installer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Inno Setup. It has a good scripting language along with a wizard if you don't want to script. It's also free (unless you are deploying commercial applications).